# Germany: Right to work without a SSN and National ID number

Tags: employment, germany, immigration

I am in Germany on a spousal visa. My visa states "Erwerbtätigkeit erlaubt" i.e. I can work here. I have a Steuernummer (tax number) and I have finished my Anmeldung (registration) at the Bürgeramt (citizen office).

I don't have a National ID number, nor a Socialversicherungsnummer yet. I am still waiting for an appointment with the Ausländerbehörde (immigration office). My company is asking for these to draw up my employment contract.

Can I legally work here before these are processed i.e. if my company were to draw up the contract and I later provided those numbers, is that legal?

Comment: 1. You must have health insurance, possibly you are currently insured via your spouse. 2. If you have an "Aufenthaltstitel", you can just go to your insurance and tell them you need a "Sozialversicherungsnummer" because you have a job offer and will start working (which means your insurance status will change). 3. Your employer could do this for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### You are required to give teh SSN before starting work

Everybody working is required to pay Social Security. To allocate your portion, the employer needs the SSN. The employer can't employ you without the SSN.

So you need to request your SSN from the respective offices. The paper SSN slip will be delivered by the [Rentenversicherung](https://www.deutsche-rentenversicherung.de/DRV/DE/Rente/Allgemeine-Informationen/Sozialversicherungsausweis/Sozialversicherungsausweis.html), and you might inquire with them for assistance.